# Including a personal.h library in C code callable from R

Tags: c, r

I've been struggling to find proper information on the web to solve this problem, in case it is an easy task please guide me through.

My final goal is to write some R functions that call C subroutines with the .Call function. In general there are no problems in doing this when R.h and Rinternals.h are sufficient.
My problem is: I would need to use in the C code some functions that are in a "personal.h" C library. I already compiled this library with gcc, but if I just try to add

```
#include "personal.h"
```

at the beginning after

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
```

like I would do if it was a standalone C file, when I then call any function from that package in the code, while compiling with R CMD SHLIB I get an error message telling me that it was not possible to find that function.
What should I do in order to include a C library in a C routine callable from R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the "Writing R Extensions" manual which came with your copy of R.

Here, you need `PKG_CPPFLAGS` to tell R about your include files / headers. Later, you will need to tell it about your library.

Look at other small packages using C code as eg [my digest package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=digest).  And yes, there are in fact numerous tutorials on the Web for this too.

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow. It is customary to "accept" an answer (click on the tickmark) and/or "upvote it" (click on the upward-facing triangle) to signal that it helped.